# Why do links in UITextView sometimes appear black and underlined?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I noticed a behaviour of `UITextView` in iOS, where auto detected links and phone numbers do not appear in UITextView's tint color, but black and underlined instead.

It appears to be related to other surrounding links. My guess is, that iOS tries to autodetect whole contact information.

However I don't want this behaviour in my app. What is this behaviour, and more importantly: *How do I override it?* I want links and phone numbers always to use the selected tint color. Setting the `linkTextAttributes` does not help either.

All of the following examples were made with a new, empty project containing a single `UITextView`; Data Detectors set to Phone Number, Link and Address.

Example 1:
[image: Example 1]
Example 2:
[image: Example 2]
Example 3:
[image: Example 3]

**EDIT:** In case I did not word my question clearly enough: I want data detection to happen, but in a consistent way. Every phone number and link should appear blue and **not** black and underlined.

My actual app pretty much looks like example 1, although with fewer phone numbers. The blue and black mix just doesn't look right.

I've also added a screenshot of a sample project. There's no code involved. Open Xcode, create an empty project, drop an UITextView in your storyboard and enter my example text. Enable data detectors and run the app:

[image: Screenshot of sample Xcode project]

Comment: Do you have any code to show us? I tried and I can't reproduce this behavior

Comment: No code. Open Xcode, create an empty project, drop an UITextView in your storyboard and enter my example text. Enable data detectors and run the app. In case it helps, I'm using Xcode 10.2 on macOS Mojave 10.14.3

Comment: @Maxime I've added a screenshot of a sample project showing the weird behaviour. No code involved.

Comment: convert you string into simple string  before assigning to textView.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan What exactly do you mean by simple string? The last screenshot shows my text entered directly into UITextView's text property. It's not an AttributedString.

Comment: when you get string from JSON it is attributed string after converting to simple string it will not add colors + underlines + links etc it will show as you want it

Comment: @AbuUlHassan Why do you think I don't want any colors or links?

Comment: sorry my mistake in reading, why don't you try setting tint color after assigning text to textView ?

Comment: That does change the blue text to the color of my choice, however the black underlined links stays unaffected. I guess I'm gonna open a TSI at Apple.

Comment: @Physikbuddha did you found the solution?

Comment: @SameerAzeem Unfortunately I did not, so I sold this as a feature to my client ...

Comment: Did you contact apple? what they had about this issue?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: @WideAngleTechnology No, eventually I stopped caring and didn't take further research into this. I'm still interested in why and how to solve it, though.